# Why does my Bootstrap row containing Snook's Simple jQuery Slideshow have a height of 0?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I'm implementing Snook's Simple jQuery Slideshow on my Bootstrap 3 website.

Check it out here: https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/more-simple-slideshow

For some reason, the row containing the slideshow has a height of 0, so all the following text is appearing on top of my slideshow images.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row bottom-margin">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Splash1.jpg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Splash2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

...

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.slideshow > :gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');}, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

and the CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
}

.slideshow > * {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

My troubleshooting revealed that div height being 0 is commonly caused by floating children, but I don't believe that's my problem here. I could be wrong, I'm a novice.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. In this case it's not a float but the `position: absolute` that's preventing the children's height from being applied to the parent. In this case, I'd recommend setting a height on the slideshow itself.

Comment: Oh, good to know! That would be the answer to my question then. Maybe this is for another question, but I was hoping to make the slideshow responsive and setting a fixed height would kill that... any suggestions, besides brute forcing it with media queries or something?

Comment: For anyone interested, I've found the perfect solution for what I'm after: http://responsiveslides.com/

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the demo page, fixed width (500px) and height (332px) values are given to the wrapper div `.fadein`.

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
    <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
    <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fadein {
    position: relative;
    height: 332px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Ahh, that's right... I was trying to make the slideshow responsive and didn't realize that position:absolute would screw up the layout. Any suggestions how to make the slideshow resize with Bootstrap's responsive layout? I could also start another question for this.

Comment: For anyone interested, I've found the perfect solution: http://responsiveslides.com/